# DDMS file not found error in Eclipse due to changed Android SDK directory

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently uninstalled the Android SDK from a directory and re-installed it in another. I changed the path to variable "Android" in "Environment Variables" after. I have all the other resources installed, still it is showing me red error icons everywhere when I create a new project ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgTeS.jpg)). The error message is "DDMS file not found: hprof-conv.exe", and it is showing the  path where I installed the SDK before. What could be the possible cause for this and how to resolve it?

Comment: Try cleaning your project. If that doesn't work, post the actual error message -- or is it just little red icons on everything?

Comment: Tried cleaning....

Comment: And yes, there are small red icons on everything!

Comment: I've added a screen-shot in the question!

Comment: Your question is not specific. What kind of err you getting? See the "Console" output. and post it.

Comment: Console is showing

Comment: DDMS file not found : hprof-conv.exe     But the thing is, it is showing the path where I've installed the SDK before. How to change the path for DDMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a problem with SDK i think. You have not properly add appcompat_v7 lib to your project.
1. Right Click on your project
2. Choose Properties
3. click on Android
4. see your scree is like this
[image]

5. Click add
6. Choose appcompat_v7
7. Click Ok

Comment: But I never had to add the library manually before. Why it happened now?

Answer (score 0):

To change the Android SDK location in Eclipse, open preferences and under Android you can browse and select the new location